# How to write a condition in bash

Tags: bash

check even number - OK

```
if [ $(( $n % 2 )) -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "$n is even number"
fi
```

how to check odd number ?

```
if [ $(( $n % ????? )) -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "$n is odd number"
fi
```

Thank

Answer (score 4):

Use "not equal 0":

```
if [ $(( $n % 2)) -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "$n is odd"
fi
```

See also: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

You can also use "n%2 equals 1" since the remainder of an odd number divided by two is one:

```
if [ $(( $1 % 2)) -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "$1 is odd"
fi
```

But the former (not equal 0) is the more general case, so I would prefer it.

Comment: Negated expressions can take a bit of practice to get comfortable with in the beginning, but when you do, they are invaluable. +1

Answer (score 2):

All the answers above use a single square bracket `[` which is outdated in `bash` (we're talking about `bash`, right?). The **best** practice to achieve the determination of an odd or even number `n` is:

```
if (( n%2==0 )); then
    printf "%d is even\n" $n
else
    printf "%d is odd\n" $n
fi
```

or, as the OP wants it, i.e., check if `n` is odd:

```
if (( n%2 )); then
    printf "%d is odd\n" $n
fi
```

Comment: A little whitespace would help: `(( n%2 == 0 ))`

Comment: true. however writing code for readability and maintainability is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n "Enter numnber : "
read n 
rem=$(( $n % 2 )) 
if [ $rem -eq 0 ]then  
   echo "$n is even number"
else  
  echo "$n is odd number"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the simplicity of:

```
x=8; ((x%2)) || echo even

x=7; ((x%2)) && echo odd
```